How to add properties to a property?
I have a Pojo with various properties, such as
class Book {
  public String title;
}

(Getters and setters left out for brevity.)
Now I want to have properties for such properties, e.g. "this title value was read from config.yaml line 3 column 5". (That's the use case I have, but I guess there are more.)
I could add a title_src property no problem.
Doing that for dozens of properties is a lot of boilerplate though.
There's also coupling. In the above example, error messages need to know about the meta-property, actual processing does not.
A Map from property to meta-property?
That would decouple, but I see no good way to construct a key without going through reflection, and the key would have to be an object/propertyname combination.
A StringWithSource type? That's going to make every usage of the property know about the type, so we have very strong coupling, though reflectionless.
I need a way to describe more information about my properties.

I've edited your post to remove the questions that could lead to opinion-based answers and that could get your question closed. Unfortunately, opinion-based questions are against the platform's guidelines.

I would handle this with a decorator class:  The Book class should not know anything about the details of its deserialization, but a wrapper class can know about them.  For example:  public class BookDeserializationResult { public record Location(int line, int column) { } Book book; Location titleLocation; Location authorLocation; }

What you describe are not properties but descriptions. It's probably best to just do this via comments next to each property. If they really need to be accessible to users during runtime, have a separate definition file that you make available instead.

Are these values all immutable? Do you read them into memory from config files, then keep the objects frozen? Or are they modifiable? You mentioned getters and setters, but I want to confirm. If modifiable, why would you care about the original source file which is no longer relevant after the field is modified?

@BasilBourque The properties themselves are immutable during actual processing, but they can be mutable while the properties are retrieved, since there can be overrides and consistency corrections. There's still a relatable source though, and if need be, one could store the entire processing history and format that into a human-readable output (thankfully, my own use case isn't that complicated).


Now I want to have properties for such properties, e.g. "this title value was read from config.yaml line 3 column 5"

It seems like that your properties should be decomposed into something more than just a simple value (String, int, or other), since you've talked about the need for a title source, a title line, a title column, and probably even more, for the title property alone.
A solution could be to refactor your title property into a more complex class, for example TitleInfo, exhibiting the following properties: value, src, line, column, etc.
class TitleInfo {
    private String value;
    private String src;
    private int line;
    private int column;

    ...
}

class Book {
    private TitleInfo title;
}

However, if we push this idea even further, we could generalize it and extend it to the other dozen of fields of your Book class. As a matter of fact, you could create a generic class PropertyInfo<T> that could represent a generic property of value T accompanied by all its details (src, line, column, etc.).
class PropertyInfo<T> {
    private T value;
    private String src;
    private int line;
    private int column;

    ...
}

class Book {
    private PropertyInfo<String> title;
    private PropertyInfo<String> author;
    private PropertyInfo<BigDecimal> price;

    ...
}


Ah right, I forgot to mention that. It's a pretty strong coupling between deserialization and DTO, so I have been dismissing that. But maybe I actually need it everywhere that some validation rule deep in the business logic triggers, and hoisting all these validations into the place where deserialization happens, while certainly doable, just creates another coupling, this time between faraway code locations. So maybe I was too hasty in ruling this out.
